# RHoMobile Error - Webpage not Available Error

Tags: android, rhomobile, rhodes

I am building a very simple application in rhodes. 
In my app I have 4 different model with CRUD operation and have no web-service interaction.

Some times I am getting error like "Webpage not Available" in android tablet.

it is working file for iPAD and also in Android simulator.

I am using rhodes-3.4.2 and the android (version 3.2) tablet.

I tried to find out the the reason for app crash with this error - "Webpage not Available", but did not able to find out any clue to the solutions.

can you please guide me to solve this issue, I need to solve this issue ASAP.

Thank you to all of u

Comment: Are you still facing this issue?

Comment: This is the problem with Android version (Version 3.x). when we upgrade the android version in device to 4.x, we did not face this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Possible this is a bug in Rhodes/Rhomobile. I had this issue too, but not for all Android 3 devices, but only on those that do not have 3G (only WiFi). More details on https://developer.motorolasolutions.com/thread/3976